# How can I bind Business Object with RDLC designer without database?

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am using Visual Studio 2017 community edition. I could not see any option on my rdlc designer to bind it to my business object (C# class). It always asks to choose dataset > data source but it only allows to connect with database. What  If I want rdlc designer to bind with my c# class. As I will be populating data to IList manually.

What's the best way to bind it my rdlc designer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be of suitable help for you.
[Using Custom Data Source to create RDLC Reports](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/473844/Using-Custom-Data-Source-to-create-RDLC-Reports)